# SQL Server - Insert Blank Rows after row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query for SQL server (2014). This query is then processed by my application that exports the result set to excel.

I have been asked if I can add space underneath each row, as the spreadsheet will be printed and they would like to make notes on it.

I have tried adding carriage returns to my query to try and stretch out the height of the column so

```
(CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)) as 'Blank Column'
```

But excel didn't pick up the returns.

The only other thing I can think of is to add 4-5 blank rows after each row with data, I'm just not sure how to do that, or even if it's possible

Comment: Have you tried Char(10)?

Comment: You Sir, are a hero. Thank you haha

Comment: Have you tried `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`?

Comment: No problemo Happy to help :)

Comment: why mess with your query? the application that exports your data should handle this issue.

Comment: I mess with my query because it's half 4 on a Friday afternoon ;)

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid they could have increased the height of all rows before printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(10),5) AS [Blank Column]
```